# How to use all the numbers in a range of a for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, range, geo, tweets

I am trying to print the location of a set of tweets. 
It is a list with ten dictionaries. I want the location of all ten to be displayed. When I use range it takes just one value. `tweets` is the list with ten dictionaries. `statuses` is the key and `geo` is the object which has the coordinates of the tweet.

```
for j in range (0,9):
    st1 = tweets[j]['statuses'][j]['geo']
print(j,st1)
```

Comment: It is unclear what your issue is. Can you share sample of your list of dictionaries?

Comment: Not sure if I understood that right, but maybe [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html) could help.

Comment: It seems the print is outside of the for loop (its indentation should match that of the previous line).

Comment: Thanks, the indentation was wrong.

Comment: I am not completely sure what exactly you want to accomplish. Are you asking on how to do a reverse lookup geo-coordinates -> location? Or do you have issues printing the geo coordinates? In that case: you are using `j` twice, which causes you to look for the tenth tweet into the tenth entry in `statuses` which somehow looks like it may not be what you really want (indentation issue aside - I just assume that there may be some whitespace missing in the code example)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of 10 dictionaries with the structure you are describing I would do

```
for i,d in enumerate(tweets):
    print(i, d['statuses']['geo']
```

Answer (score 1):

your print statement is out of for loop. You must write like this:

```
for j in range (0,9):
    st1 = tweets[j]['statuses'][j]['geo']
    print(j,st1)
```

**UPDATE:** 
I think that, you want to display all tweets and all statuses. In that case you must use nested for loops like:

```
for j in range(0, 9):
    for i in range(len(tweets[j]['statuses'])):
        st1 = tweets[j]['statuses'][i]['geo']
        print(j, i, st1)
```

after some optimizations it will look like (if you don't need index):

```
for tweet in tweets:
    for status in tweet['statuses']:
        st1 = status['geo']
        print(st1)
```

Comment: I had figured out displaying statuses but was stuck with getting all of them displayed. This helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation was wrong.

```
for j in range (0,10):
   st1 = tweets[j]['statuses'][j]['geo']
   print(j,st1)
```

This fixed it.

Comment: which I told you on my answer )

Comment: yes, Thanks. :)